# Which third party shopping-cart can easily be integrated with MODX Revolution?

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, modx, modx-revolution

Since there's currently no complete solution to build a modX powered website with integrated shop, I was wondering which would be the way to go, to achieve this with a third party cart.

The integration in the frontend should be very close, so you can't distinguish the parts coming from modx with the parts (cart, product listings, product views) and everything should work without heavy js processing. On the other hand it would be totally ok to manage content in the modX backend and products in the shopping carts backend, independent of each other.

There should be a convenient way for i18n and a big range of (international) payment methods, everything should run on own hardware and it would be lovely to use an open source cart. In addition, it would be a big plus if the commerce software would be well suited to sell digital goods.

A pretty long wish list, I know, but I expect a combination of modX with something as powerful as Magento, XtCommerce, Opencart or the likes would be a really nice way to realize a big website with integrated shop.

I'm absolutely willing to spend a lot of time for the integration, I'm only very unsure, if there's something that can be considered the way to go for a project like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a MODX shopping cart addon called SimpleCart: [modxsimplecart.com](http://www.modxsimplecart.com/)

It is built using standard MODX techniques (templates, TVs, chunks & snippets) and the output is fully customizable. Because of this, it's well integrated into the back end as well.

Not free nor Open Source though.

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks a lot. I already contacted the developer about some of the features.

Answer (score 2):

In the modx forums, I found reference to [FoxyCart](http://www.foxycart.com/) which seems like it can integrate well. I found a video tutorial though to help with that:

http://www.my619.com/foxy-cart-modx-tutorial-1

Comment: I already read about this one and maybe going to try it because of the lack of good alternatives, but it doesn't fully fulfill the requirements since it's a pay-for-use service that doesn't work on your own server. On the other hand it seems to integrate very well and might still be the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

i´m building a shop in simplecart atm. also soon there will be a new one http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=83288&page=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm prefer [shopmodxbox](http://shopmodx.modxclub.ru/). You can download it from our repository: http://rest.modxstore.ru/extras/

But be careful! It's a package with working shop. Install it only at clear site.

[Here](https://github.com/Fi1osof/ShopModxBox) you can find sources.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for answering. It would be great if you could elobarate a bit about which of the whished features are present in your solution.

Comment: Hi. That box is divided to [individual modules](http://goo.gl/e36g1e) which works together:
1. basket,billing,shopmodxbox,shopmodxgroupedit- base shop modules
2. modcaptcha,modhybridauth — captcha & social auth module
3. modxsite — glue layer for all modules. There are base processors for xpdo objects output, form sending processor and directory for modxsmarty templates
4. edinayakassa is one of payment modules. It works in Russia but you can build you own module using base create [processor](http://goo.gl/GXBmJM).

[Demo](http://shopmodx.modxclub.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [minishop2](https://docs.modx.pro/en/components/minishop2) This is great e-commerce opensource MODX Revo shop. I used it in some projects. Not very simple, but in some way great to use.